# Redefine RDC Channel Check Rate during runtime

Tags: contiki, cooja

How to can change channel check rate of a node in during runtime on Contiki OS? I use the ContikiMAC RDC protocol.

Comment: This is a short, specific question with a (quite) short and specific answer that could be useful to many people using Contiki - a very good fit for SO. It's quite annoying to see questions like this downvoted because someone did not understand them.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not supported by the OS.

If you want, you can implement this yourself by changing `NETSTACK_RDC_CHANNEL_CHECK_RATE` from a preprocessor definition to a variable and doing the same with `CYCLE_TIME` (in `contikimac.c`).

However, the current limitation is there for a reason. If different nodes in a network have different radio duty cycles, ContikiMAC will fail to work as intended. It's not a good idea to change the RDC unless you do it for all nodes at the same time.

Comment: thank you for answer
In fact, I want frequency to change based on the distance of the node from the sink. Is there a way for this?